# EF 4.1 Poco generation from multiple linked EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, poco, code-first, edmx

I would like to :

- define one first EDMX for generating pocos into one first assembly (base library)
- define another EDMX for generatiog pocos into a second assembly
- have the entities defined into the second EDMX mention some entities of the first EDMX
  -- through inheritance or association

Is it possible to some how reuse/import an EDMX into a second one ?
Is it possible to do this across assemblies ?

My ultimate goals are to

- have sucessive layers of pocos (and related repositories...) by decreasing reusability.
- compare two sets of EDMX, each onerepresenting a version of a given database, in order to
- compute the delta of schemas (xml difference...) and
- (semi) automatically generate the code to migrate the content of the database.

Any hint much appreciated.
Thanks.

Thierry